# Sticky title-bar is not sticking

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I am using Foundation to build a sticky menu. The top-bar sticks with no problem, but when scaled down to small the title-bar does not stick.  What am I missing?

```
    <div data-sticky-container >
        <div id="mobileMenu" class="title-bar" data-responsive-toggle="main-menu" data-hide="medium"
             data-sticky data-options="marginTop:0;" style="width:100%"
             data-top-anchor="top">
            <button class="menu-icon" type="button" data-toggle="main-menu"></button>
            <div class="title-bar-title">Menu</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-sticky-container>
        <div class="top-bar" id="main-menu"
             data-sticky data-options="marginTop:0;" style="width:100%"
             data-top-anchor="1">
            <div class="top-bar-left">
                <ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
                     <!--links here-->
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: try to add on yuor css .title-bar, .top-bar { position: fixed, top: 0; width: 100%; }

Comment: That solved it. Put it in an answer and I will accept it.  Still curious as to why my original code doesn't just work.

Comment: On second thought I see that I can't anchor it to an element.

Comment: what do you mean you cant anchor it to an element?

Comment: Say I want to anchor it to the bottom of a header.  It should be anchored to the bottom of the header until the header scrolls out of view, at which point the title-bar becomes fixed to the top of the view.

Comment: you can use jquery to do that, get the height of the header using jquery then compare it to window.pageYOffset on window scroll event, then use if statement to compare the header height and window.pageYOffset to make menu when to become sticky and not.

Answer (score 3):

The solution here is to wrap both elements in an element with the sticky attribute:

```
<nav data-sticky-container>
    <div data-sticky data-margin-top="0" data-sticky-on="small">
        <div class="title-bar" data-responsive-toggle="menu" data-hide-for="medium">
            <button class="menu-icon" type="button" data-toggle></button>
            <div class="title-bar-title">Mobile Menu Title</div>
        </div>
        <div id="menu" class="top-bar">
            <div class="top-bar-left">
                <ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
                    <li class="has-submenu">
                        <a href="#">Drop Down Menu Option 1</a>
                        <ul class="submenu menu vertical" data-submenu>
                            <li><a>Sub-Menu Option 1</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu Option 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu Option 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Strangely setting `.title-bar, .top-bar { 
    position: fixed, 
    top: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
}` did not help. Instead this solution worked as a charm.

Answer (score 0):

try to add position fixed on your menu container

```
.title-bar, .top-bar { 
    position: fixed, 
    top: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
}
```